# How to prevent ._ (dot underscore) files?

Tags: sshfs, textmate2

I am using Textmate 2 to edit a rails project on remote Linux server via [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

When I save a file (e.g. `README.rdoc`) there is another file created (i.e. `._README.rdoc`):

```
-rw-rw-r--  1  4096 Feb 17 17:19 ._README.rdoc
-rw-rw-r--  1   486 Feb 17 17:19 README.rdoc
```

The Textmate doc mentioned [how to disable extended attributes](https://manual.macromates.com/en/saving_files#extended_attributes_metadata.html):

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDocumentDisableFSMetaData 1
```

but `._` files are still created after the above `defaults write`.

Is there a way to disable creation of `._` files when using sshfs + Textmate 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[To disable Extended Attributes](https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Hidden-Settings) in Textmate 2, use:

```
defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview volumeSettings '{ "/Users/ohho/Mount/" = { extendedAttributes = 0; }; }'
```

Where `/Users/ohho/Mount/` is the parent folder of all my sshfs mounted folders.

Answer (score 0):

As I have tried with following command THIS IS NOT WORKING :
    NOT WORKING:-"defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDocumentDisableFSMetaData 1"

```
I have taken reference from :
```

https://github.com/textmate/textmate/wiki/Hidden-Settings 
and its working fine now.

```
TextMate use extended attributes to store caret position, etc.

On file systems which don’t support extended attributes
```

(most network file systems), OS X will create an auxiliary file with 
a dot-underscore prefix (e.g. ._filename).

```
If you don’t want these files, you can disable the use of extended
```

attributes. This is presently controlled with the volumeSettings key. 
Its values are (1) an associative array with path prefix; and (2) another associative array with settings for that path. (Presently, only extendedAttributes
 is supported.)

```
So, if we wanted to disable extended attributes for files under /net/:
```

defaults write com.macromates.TextMate.preview volumeSettings '{ "/net/" = { extendedAttributes = 0; }; }'